# Pass expression as argument in R Survey package

Tags: r, survey

I have a question regarding calling variables in `svycontrast()` function with `survey` package.
I'm trying to automate some contrast against a fixed parameter. I can do that no problem like this:

```
library(survey)    
data(api)

dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)

diff <- svyby(~enroll, by = ~cnum, dclus1, na.rm.all = FALSE, svymean, covmat = T, vartype = "se")

parameter <- 550

svycontrast(diff, quote(`1` - parameter))

#           nlcon SE
# contrast 2.8182  0
```

However, I have been for hours trying to figure out how to call that `rowname` `1`, but with different approaches I keep getting mostly the following error message:

```
row <- quote(1)

svycontrast(diff, quote(row - parameter))
Error in row - parameter : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I modified the title to attract more attention ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use `bquote` instead of `quote` here

```
> row <- 1

> svycontrast(diff, bquote(.(as.name(row)) - parameter))
          nlcon SE
contrast 2.8182  0
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use `substitute` combined with `as.symbol`:

```
row <- 1

substitute(row - parameter, list(row = as.symbol(row)))
# `1` - parameter

svycontrast(diff, substitute(row - parameter, list(row = as.symbol(row))))

#          nlcon SE
#contrast 2.8182  0
```

Comment: It was really difficult to choose a right answer between yours and @ThomasisCoding since both use very similar functions. I just chose the more succint one.

Comment: Also upvoted @ThomasIsCoding : gave me the opportunity to discover `bquote`

Comment: Your answer is nice as well, upvoted already :)